# Ruby equivalent of python nonlocal

Tags: ruby, closures

I am trying to write a closure in Ruby. This is the code written in Python:

```
def counter():
    x = 0
    def increment(y):
        nonlocal x
        x += y
        print(x)
    return increment
```

Is there a "nonlocal" equivalent in Ruby so I can access and make changes to the variable x from inside increment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nonlocal` keyword tells Python which variables to capture. In Ruby, you don't need such a keyword: all variables are captured unless explicitly mentioned otherwise.

So, the Ruby equivalent to your Python code translates almost directly:

```
counter = -> {
  x = 0
  ->y {
    x += y
    puts x
  }
}

i = counter.()

i.(2)
# 2

i.(3)
# 5
```

It would probably be more idiomatic to use a method for `counter`, though:

```
def counter
  x = 0
  ->y {
    x += y
    puts x
  }
end

i = counter

i.(2)
# 2

i.(3)
# 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like:

```
class CGroup
  def counter
    @x ||= 0
    lambda do |y|
      @x += y
    end
  end
end
```

Then:

```
group = CGroup.new
c = group.counter
c.call(1)
=> 1
c.call(1)
=> 2
```

I'm not aware of a direct analog for Python's `nonlocal`.

**EDIT**: The instance variable is unnecessary, and the same thing can be achieved with a variable local to the method.  This makes the class superfluous, although much in Ruby takes place within the context of an object.

Comment: That create a completely unnecessary object though.

Comment: @delnan: agreed.  I don't like it.  The thought was to avoid namespace pollution by using globals.

Comment: NB You *have* to avoid globals to achieve anything remotely similar to the function in the question (the returned functions are independent).

Answer (score 2):

Since there is objection to using an object, why not just use a lambda?

```
counter_generator = ->(){
  x ||= 0
  ->(y){
    x += y
    puts x
  }
}

i = counter_generator.call
=> #<Proc:0x00000100867508@(irb):17 (lambda)>
i.call(1)
1
=> nil
i.call(1)
2
=> nil
```

Note that the incrementor actually returns nil because you've only specified to output the value of x, not to return it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Most closure examples online only used lambdas to create new functions so I wasn't sure on how to go about making a closure that maintained some sort of state.

Comment: Glad to help. You can use the body of `counter_generator` within any ruby method, be it a method or proc or lambda, and it will work the same. The outer lambda isn't really important, it just saves some typing really.